# Originator doesn't have entitlement - ImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I am trying to save the image from a URL from my server:

```
let urlString = "http://someValidUrlToAnImage.png"
let url = URL(string: urlString )
                                   
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
                print( "Image saved !!!!" )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It was working fine before, but now I am getting this error:

> Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)}>

I am testing it via Xcode and USB cable.
I have added all the entitlements to Xcode's plist and to the AppStoreConnect site.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: You should not use `Data(contentsOf:)` to access data from network locations. It states this in the documentation for that function. Start by switching to a `URLSession` approach. Also, in general, never use `try ?` as errors are simply discarded.  At the very least catch errors and print them. Similarly, pass a completion handler to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` and print any resulting error